# How can I read a file in Internal Storage without declaring the permission?

Tags: java, android, file, permissions

I'm writing an app that allows users to import their own data (via .zip's, .png's etc.) from an external location such as their downloads folder.

My app is correctly getting the file path from the URI, however I do not wish to require the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my app, which I need in order to read the file the user is providing me. I feel like Android should allow my app read permission to this file, since the user selected it.

Is there a way to have Android copy this file to a temporary location where I can read it, so that I do not need to ask the user for this permission?

Comment: I think you meant you need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for your app to READ files. Second, what's wrong asking the user at install-time for the permission the read from external storage?

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will implicitly also grant READ permission as well. I do have functionality that's optional that needs the WRITE permission, and I figure the less permission prompts the better. 

I'm trying to keep the app functional with as little permissions as possible, as some people might rather it not have that permission.

Comment: "I feel like Android should allow my app read permission to this file, since the user selected it" -- how exactly is the user selecting it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the permission, then there is a way for Android4.4 and above. Let the user import the data into the programdirectory, see also:

> Starting in Android 4.4, the owner, group and modes of files on
>   external storage devices are now synthesized based on directory
>   structure. This enables apps to manage their package-specific
>   directories on external storage without requiring they hold the broad
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. For example, the app with package
>   name com.example.foo can now freely access
>   Android/data/com.example.foo/ on external storage devices with no
>   permissions. These synthesized permissions are accomplished by
>   wrapping raw storage devices in a FUSE daemon.

Taken from this page -> https://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html

Comment: I just downloaded an app which never asked for permission to read or write on external storage but has access to my storage.. how is this possible? I even checked the permissions and permission to external storage was denied. I'm not talking about app accessing it's own storage but reading users' data.